# Mechanize - form has no submit button

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

> I want to login to this website : "https://www.flipkart.com/account/login"
>   this site doesn't have any name or id for the form only has class
>
> HTML login page code looks like this:

```
<div>
<form autocomplete="on">
    <div class="_39M2dM JB4AMj">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus="" class="_2zrpKA _2rqcw- _1dBPDZ" value="rockingkiran.2000@gmail.com">
        <span class="s-YM1W _2rqcw-"></span>
        <label class="b5konl _2rqcw-"><span>Enter Email/Mobile number</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="_39M2dM JB4AMj">
        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="_2zrpKA _3v41xv _1dBPDZ" value="">
        <span class="s-YM1W"></span>
        <label class="b5konl"><span>Enter Password</span></label>
        <a class="_21JmK0 _1__46T" tabindex="-1"><span>Forgot?</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="_1avdGP">
        <button class="_2AkmmA _1LctnI _7UHT_c" type="submit">
            <div class="_2VTdOs _1_qmw3"><svg class="_2zN0mv" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                <circle stroke="#fff" class="_1VgS7d" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10"></circle></svg>
            </div>
            <span>Login</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

> I am trying to fill in and submit it using the below code:

```
import mechanize
import http.cookiejar


def log_in():
    # Browser
    br = mechanize.Browser()

    # Cookie Jar
    cj = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    # Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

    # The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
    br.open('https://www.flipkart.com/account/login')

    # Select the second (index one) form 
    br.select_form(nr=1)

    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

    # User credentials
    br.form.set_value(E-Mail, nr=0)
    br.form.set_value(Password, nr=1)

    print(br.form.controls[0])
    print(br.form.controls[1])

    # Login
    br.submit()
```

> When I submit the above code its not logging in
>
> Please tell me which part for my code I need to correct

Comment: HTML code is incomplete. Where is the form closing tag `</form>`? And, there is a submit button. The last div has the button with type `submit`

Comment: @MoosaSaadat Yes html has submit button, but when I run the above python code its not logging in.